# Playing audio chunks in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, html5-audio, web-audio-api, chunked-encoding

I have a node js API which is streaming a mp3 audio file like this:

```
app.get('/music', (req, res) => {
   const music = fsExtra.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/musics/myMusic.mp3"));
    music.pipe(res);
});
```

and in react side I'm getting audio chunks like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/music/")
        .then((response) => {
            return response.text();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

and the output is something like this:

[image of data received from node js server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHnsK.png)

how can I play these chunks and play the music?
I don't want to wait for the whole music file to load. I want to play it while loading chunks.
something like this project:

[Streams Audio Playback](https://fetch-stream-audio.anthum.com)

can you please give me some easy to understand code example?
I don't want to use `<audio>` tag because I want to create audio visualization in the future.