# Playing music while loading in html / react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, audio, audio-streaming

I have been using the following html:

```
<audio id="audio" loop autoPlay> 
    <source src="./bgmusic.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
```

However this makes the page load the whole audio file before playing, instead of playing it while streaming.
It is not possible for me to setup a streaming service at the backend, as given here:
[Playing audio chunks in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67903831/playing-audio-chunks-in-react)

Is there any way to use js for playing the music as it loads? It **does not have to be mp3** but any format that makes this feasible. I tried looking if it was possible to get some sort of loading progress context from  element and use the incomplete loaded data as src for another music element, however I am at the end of ideas.

I have been developing a frontend in ReactJS.

Please advise.